# Numpy: reading multiple columns from multiple files

Tags: python, numpy

I have several files from which I'd like to input data and possibly doing it in one go, I mean not extracting each columns at the time.

If it would be only one file, I would do it using:

```
data1, data2, data3 = zip(*numpy.loadtxt("myfile.data",usecols=((0,3,4))))
```

"unzipping" the columns after reading them but as I have several input files I don't know how to adapt it, except for reading them one by one and appending in the end; but I'm reading quite a huge amount of data (around 20gb) so I'm thinking that this is not the most efficient way of doing it (may involve a lot of data moving around in RAM).

Do you know of something doing a more proper job?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provided you have enough ram, moving data in memory is likely to take little time compared to reading that data from disk. I'd say just read them one at a time and join them together after all of the files have been read into its own array. This way copying will be done only once. If you want to append, make sure your array uses fortran format. This way appending would probably be faster (provided number of rows is the same) because numpy would not have to rearrange data and should be able to create new array by copying two large consecutive chunks of data.

Comment: How are they stored? `data1` in one file, `dataX` in the Xfile? Or each file contains some proportion of `dataX`?

Comment: @CTZhu: Each files contains some part of each one, I need to read them all to compose the complete columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data1` `data2` `data3` only account for small percentage of you 20 gb data (say if there are many many columns and you only take 3 out of those), these lines will read them all at once to RMA:

```
data_all=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(item,usecols=((0,3,4))) for item in your_file_list])
data1, data2, data3=data_all.T
```